# Uncaught Type Error: View is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have Uncaught Type Error : UserRegisterView is not a constructor.I dont understand this error.I looked all code but i dont find it.
Sorry of my bad english.Please help me

Thanks for answer

**UPDATED**

UserRegisterView is here

```js
var UserRegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({

    model: User,
    el: '#form',
    events: {
        'click input[id="infoWeek"]': 'infoWeek',
        'click input[id="infoMonth"]': 'infoMonth'
    },

    infoWeek: function() {

        this.$el.find("#dayOfMonth").hide();
        this.render();
    },

    infoMonth: function() {

        this.$el.find("#dayOfWeek").hide();
        this.render();

    }
});

var AddUserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".page"),
    events: {
        'click #saveUser': 'saveUser'
    },
    saveUser: function() {
        var user = new User();
        user.set({
            username: $("#username").val(),
            lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
            regNumber: $("#regNumber").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
            departmentName: $("#departmentName").val(),
            email: $("#email").val(),
            role: $("#role").val()
        });
        user.save();

        if (document.getElementById('isOpen').checked) {
            user.set("isOpen", $("#isOpen").val("1"));
            user.save();
        } else {
            user.set("isOpen", $("#isOpen").val("0"));
            user.save();
        }

        if (document.getElementById('dayOfWeek').checked) {
            user.set("dayOfWeek", $("#dayOfWeek").val());
            user.save();
        } else if (document.getElementById('dayOfMonth').checked) {
            user.set("dayOfMonth", $("#dayOfMonth").val());
            user.save();
        }


        $("#username").val("");
        $("#firstName").val("");
        $("#lastName").val("");
        $("#regNumber").val("");
        $("#password").val("");
        $("#deparmentName").val("");
        $("#email").val("");
        $("#isOpen").val("");
        $("#dayOfWeek").val("");
        $("#dayOfMonth").val("");
    },

    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        var template = Handlebars.compile(UserRegister);
        var myHtml = template(that.model.toJSON());
        that.$el.html(myHtml);
        return this;
    }
});

return {
    AddUserView: AddUserView,
    UserRegisterView: UserRegisterView
};

});
```

router user func.

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'handlebars',
    'spin',
    'app/models/LoginModel',
    'app/views/LoginView',
    'app/views/UserRegisterView'
], function($,
    _,
    Backbone,
    Handlebars,
    Spinner,
    Login,
    LoginView,
    UserRegisterView
) {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'search': 'search',
            'login': 'login',
            'travels': 'travels',
            'user': 'user',
            'menu': 'menu',
            '': 'home'

        },
        user: function() {

            disposeView(new UserRegisterView().render());

        }
```

dispose.view on util.js

```js
function disposeView(view) {
    Backbone.View.prototype.close = function() {
        this.unbind();
        this.undelegateEvents();
    };

    /* Şu anki viewi yok et */
    if (this.currentView !== undefined) {
        this.currentView.close();
    }

    /* Yeni view oluştur. */
    this.currentView = view;
    this.currentView.delegateEvents();

    return this.currentView;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `UserRegisterView` anywhere. Also, why so many calls to `user.save()`? And why the mixture of `getElementById` calls and jQuery calls?

Comment: Sorry writing wrong edited.Can i save multiple textbox in one save() method?And yh mixed a little,but that's easy for me.Is that a problem?

Comment: But you still have `UserView: UserRegisterView` in the `return`. Generally you make a bunch of `set(key, value)` calls (or one `set({ ... })` to set a bunch of values at once) and then a single `save` to save all the changes at once.

Comment: updated but "UserRegisterView is not a constructor" error still here @muistooshort

Comment: Can you produce a self-contained demo? I don't see where you're saying `new UserRegisterView`.

Comment: oh sorry. i forget adding router.js . I'm calling user func in Router.js @muistooshort

Comment: But how do you get `UserRegisterView` into the router function?

Comment: added the post define code.But i dont think about it @muistooshort

Comment: Yeah two view in 1 define view.But main view return on define.I'm sure of that.But i dont know why i'm getting this error.So strange.@muistooshort @TJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's happening

Your `UserRegisterView` module returns an object which contains two constructors.

> ```
> return {
>     AddUserView: AddUserView,
>     UserRegisterView: UserRegisterView
> };
> ```

When using this module, what you're getting is the object above.

```
define([
    // ...
    'app/views/UserRegisterView'
], function(
    // ...
    UserRegisterView // value of the return in the module
) {
```

So you're kind of *misleading yourself by calling it `UserRegisterView`* as it's not the constructor, but the object containing the constructor.

To get a new `UserRegisterView` view instance with the current way your module is setup, you'd need to call it like so:

```
var userView = new UserRegisterView.UserRegisterView();
```

Or to create a `AddUserView` instance:

```
var addView = new UserRegisterView.AddUserView();
```

## Solutions

- Split up the module, one for each view constructor.
- Change the name so at least it's not misleading (like `UserViewsModule`)

---

## Other improvements

That being said, there are other improvements that could be made to your Backbone code.

```
var UserRegisterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    // that's useless (if not used) and not a view property.
    // model: User,

    // don't use `el` like that, especially when using the view as a shared Constructor
    el: '#form',
    events: {
        'click input[id="infoWeek"]': 'onInfoWeekClick',
        'click input[id="infoMonth"]': 'onInfoMonthClick'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        // Cache jQuery object of the view's element
        this.$dayOfMonth = this.$("#dayOfMonth");
        this.$dayOfMonth = this.$("#dayOfMonth");
        // also use the shortcut function instead of `this.$el.find()`
    }

    onInfoWeekClick: function(e) {
        this.$dayOfMonth.hide();
        // calling render here is useless unless your using it as a parent
        // view, where the child view overrides the render function.
    },

    onInfoMonthClick: function(e) {
        this.$dayOfMonth.hide();
    }
});
```

The `disposeView` function could be simplified:

```
function disposeView(view) {
    var current = this.currentView;
    if (current) current.close();
    current = this.currentView = view;
    current.delegateEvents();
    return current;
}
```

Don't change the default Backbone view prototype each time the function is called. Instead, add the function once.

```
_.extend(Backbone.View.prototype, {
    close: function() {
        this.unbind();
        this.undelegateEvents();
    },
    // any other function you want to add can go here.
});
```

In another answer, I go into details on [how to extend Backbone's core classes with requirejs transparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712868/1218980).

You're already using jQuery, so don't use JavaScript DOM API `document.getElementById('isOpen')` interspersed with jQuery selectors `$('#isOpen')`.

I made some improvements to the following view. Take the time to create yourself some utility functions (like `reset` and `getValues`) to simplify the flow of the code and encapsulate the complexity.

```
var AddUserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $(".page"),
    events: {
        'click #saveUser': 'saveUser'
    },
    // compile the template once while creating the view class
    template: Handlebars.compile(UserRegister),

    // get the selector string out of the code and place them in one place
    // easy to change and maintain.
    fields: {
        username: "#username",
        firstName: "#firstName",
        lastName: "#lastName",
        regNumber: "#regNumber",
        password: "#password",
        deparmentName: "#deparmentName",
        email: "#email",
        isOpen: "#isOpen",
        dayOfWeek: "#dayOfWeek",
        dayOfMonth: "#dayOfMonth",
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        // cache jQuery object of every field once after a render
        this.field = _.reduce(this.fields, function(fields, selector, key) {
            fields['$' + key] = this.$(selector);
            return fields;
        }, {}, this);
        return this;
    },
    reset: function() {
        // reset all the fields once without repeating code.
        _.each(this.field, function($field) {
            $field.val("");
        });
        return this;
    },
    getValues: function(keys) {
        // get the value of multiple fields returned in a nice object
        // ready to be sent to a Backbone model.
        return _.reduce(keys, function(data, key) {
            data[key] = this.field[key].val();
            return data;
        }, {}, this);
    },

    saveUser: function() {
        var field = this.field,
            user = new User(this.getValues([
                'username',
                'lastName',
                'regNumber',
                'password',
                'departmentName',
                'email',
                'role',
            ]));

        user.set({ isOpen: field.$isOpen.is(':checked') });

        if (field.$dayOfWeek.is(':checked')) {
            user.set("dayOfWeek", field.$dayOfWeek.val());
        } else if (field.$dayOfMonth.is(':checked')) {
            user.set("dayOfMonth", field.$dayOfMonth.val());
        }

        user.save();
        this.reset();
    },
});
```

In the following snippet, you're putting the context (`this`) into a local variable. I see that a lot and I could say that 90% of the times I see it on Stack Overflow questions, it makes no sense. It clearly screams copy-pasted.

> ```
> render: function() {
>     var that = this;
>     // ...
>     that.$el.html(myHtml);
>     return this;
> }
> ```

Please tell me you see that you're putting `this` into `that`, then using `that` throughout the function, then you still return `this`?!

Putting the context into a local variable is useful when the object is needed in a dynamically created callback.

```
render: function() {
    var that = this; // this is available here
    setTimeout(function() {
        // here this is not available.
        that.handleCallback();
    }, 10);
    // here we are in the same context as the first line.
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for solution.This solution works my project.